# autocompletetextview Set Selection is not working

Tags: java, android-studio

I have two autocompletetextview
the goal for example if any one select the autocompletetextview "HUB ID " position#3 then the another autocompletetextview " HUBName" must be forced to be on position 3
i.e want the both of them at the same position

```
           // HUB Name listener
        HubName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
                HubName.setSelection(pos);
                Log.d("ID Array follow pos","HUB ID in selected");
                HubID.setSelection(pos);
                HubName.setSelection(pos);

                ShltrArray.clear();
                ShltrArray.add(Shltr1Array.get(pos).toString());
                if (Shltr2Array.get(pos).toString() != "Not")
                {
                    ShltrArray.add(Shltr2Array.get(pos).toString());
                }
                ShltrAdapt.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

        });

HubName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        HubName.setSelection(position);
        HubID.setSelection(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
        HubName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HubName.showDropDown();
        

        Log.d("ID Array follow ID ", Integer.toString(HubID.getListSelection()));
        Log.d("ID Array follow Name ", Integer.toString(HubName.getListSelection()));
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the solution to index the array list to the same position of the first array then inside autocompleteTextView listener  then set text to this position as follow

```
HubName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
            HubID.setText(IDArray.get(pos).toString());}
```